# Airflow not running

Tags: airflow

I´m new to Airflow after running normal terminal statements as I do everyday:
cd ../../Airflow
bash Run.sh

I got this error

```
[2021-12-09 17:04:04,486] {db.py:815} ERROR - Automatic migration is not available
[2021-12-09 17:04:04,486] {db.py:817} ERROR - The task_fail table has 14 rows without a corresponding dag_run row. You must manually correct this problem (possibly by deleting the problem rows).
```

Can you guide me how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see your "run.sh" script. For some reason you got a new version of Airflow and the migration was run (probably that's part of your script).

What you see is airflow telling you, that migration to a new version failed because some of the rows in the DB got corrupted (there could be many reasons for that but likely a programmatic error in earlier version of airlfow or some manual modification of the db by you or some db operators, or - for example - shutting down Airlfow in a non-clean way.

You should do what the message says - you should remove the faulty rows and for that - unfortunately - you need to connect to your database and run appropriate SQL queries to delete the rows. You need to look at the table and delete the rows. i am sure you can google the righ SQL to run.

In case you are not familiar with how airflow DB works you can see at this chapter - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/upgrading.html#post-upgrade-warnings - the message there is slightly different, but the guidance on how to approach is similar. find the right table, delete the rows that are described in the message and you should be good to go.